# Lumen's url() function performing strangely

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.2

I recently did a fresh install of Lumen framework and started building a site from it. Yes I know lumen is designed only for APIs but please help me out with this.

I have placed all my views inside **/resources/views** and my templates inside **/resources/views/templates**.

Now since I had to place **[css/js/images]** somewhere, I thought placing all of that in **public/assets/[css/js/images]** would be nice.

Now in my layout when I am trying to include css - I use something like this -

```
<link href="{{ url('assets/css/something.css') }}">
```

and it works giving an output of something like this -

```
<link href="localhost/assets/css/something.css">
```

same thing works for js also but it gets strange when I try to include images. For including an image I write something like -

```
<img src ="{{ url('assets/images/someimage.jpg') }}"
```

and when I view page source, output is as I expect it to be -

```
<img src="localhost/assets/images/someimage.jpg">
```

but my console fires 404 not found errors stating someimage.jpg not found. And when I crosscheck by inspecting the image's parent, the Url is totally different soemthing like this -

```
<img src="localhost/images/someimage.jpg">
```

See, automatically omitting 'assets' from image url and resulting in 404, but I can see correct url when I view page source.

**Things I tried to resolve the issue -**

1. Cleared cache and reloaded the page.
2. Tried using asset() instead of url() but prototype of that was removed from lumen.
3. Pull out [css/js/images] folder from assets and pasted them in parent i.e. public. **This worked but then the question is why did the previous setup worked find for both css and js and caused problem only with images ?**

My other questions are -

**1. How can the url in page source be different from the one being rendered ? Just to mention in my case the url in page source worked and displayed image but since the url being renderred omitted 'assets' from path hence resulted in 404.**

**2. Is there any other good way to include these assets in views. If yes then please also mention where to put them ?**

Attaching some images/code for reference.

[Output of rendered page showing 404 errors for images but none for css.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHXiz.png)

[Output of view page source windows showing asset included in image path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYA3A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clue if this is right, but I believe you actually need to put an image stream inside that URL. Now the server is trying to retrieve some byte encoded object that isn't there.

I have no idea if it's the same case for you, but I've had many instances where I had to put in image streams instead of URLs, which I've solved this way using [this library](http://image.intervention.io/):

**Routes.php**

```
/**
* Image handling routes.
* These make sure images actually are images instead of bytecode
*/
Route::get('organization/logo/{logo}', function($logo) {
    $file = Image::make(Storage::disk('logo-image')->get($logo));
    return $file->response();
});
```

**View**

```
<img src="{{ asset('organization/logo/' . $organization->logo_path) }}" alt="">
```

I might be completely off, but I recognize what's happening with your app and this took care of the issues when I implemented it.

Comment: Hey !! Thanks for replying, I would definitely try and answer back. But for now can you please link me to any resource where I can find more information regarding the solution you gave ?

Comment: I found this pretty useful: https://m.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/3f9257/psa_uploading_interventionimages_using_storageput/ and otherwise the Intervention Image docs are pretty clear

Answer (score 0):

Check your web server configuration. It sounds like you have some type of redirect setup that redirects `assets/images/*` to just `images/*`.

As a simple test, open your "Network" tab and navigate your browser to `http://samplelumena.local/assets/images/footer1.jpg`. I'm guessing the Network trace will show a 30x (301, 302, etc.) to `http://samplelumena.local/images/footer1.jpg`, followed by the 404 for that url.